# Using MSFT SQL server XML, how to insert attributes to tags with attribute values found in a list

Tags: xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to add a new attribute to all elements that have an @Name value found in a list of names.

This is what I've got so far; it works, but it only updates one node at a time. I have to change the "PatientNames" value for each occurrence that I need to update.

```
update ListDataFormatter_Test
SET FieldDefinition.modify('
   insert attribute PlainTextPersonNotification {"True"}
   into (/Fields/Field[@Name="PatientNames"])[1]
   ')
```

I would like to be able to have it update with a single command based on a list like an 'IN' clause in standard SQL.

```
update ListDataFormatter_Test
SET FieldDefinition.modify('
  insert attribute PlainTextPersonNotification {"True"}
  into (/Fields/Field[@Name in ("PatientNames", "ProviderNames", "PracticeSettingsName", "PracticeSettingsMainAddresses", "PracticeSettingsPhones")])[1]')
```

The FieldDefinition is XML and a sample of how this looks is like this:

```
<Fields>
  <CalledDataFormatter Uid="9D7520C3-B507-463F-9CFD-18BDE5A74677" Prefix="PrimaryCare" />
  <Field Name="PatientNames" Layout="Name" />
  <Field Name="PatientPrimaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
  <Field Name="PatientSecondaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
  <Field Name="PatientDOB" Layout="Date" />
  <Field Name="PracticeSettingsName" Layout="Date" />
```

I am getting the right results but I have to create a seperate update command for each @Name value that I want to modify.

```
<Fields>
  <CalledDataFormatter Uid="9D7520C3-B507-463F-9CFD-18BDE5A74677" Prefix="PrimaryCare" />
  <Field Name="PatientNames" PlainTextPersonNotification="True" Layout="Name" />
  <Field Name="PatientPrimaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
  <Field Name="PatientSecondaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
  <Field Name="PatientDOB" Layout="Date" />
  <Field Name="PracticeSettingsName" PlainTextPersonNotification="True" Layout="Date" />
```

My list of @Name values is small now, but it is growing with every meeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit older, but you might still need a solution. Here is [FLWOR for your rescue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, FieldDefinition XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ( '<Fields>
      <CalledDataFormatter Uid="9D7520C3-B507-463F-9CFD-18BDE5A74677" Prefix="PrimaryCare" />
      <Field Name="PatientNames" Layout="Name" />
      <Field Name="PatientPrimaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
      <Field Name="PatientSecondaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
      <Field Name="PatientDOB" Layout="Date" />
      <Field Name="PracticeSettingsName" Layout="Date" />
    </Fields>');
```

--declare the list of `@Name` values

```
  DECLARE @ListOfNames VARCHAR(100)='PatientNames ProviderNames PracticeSettingsName PracticeSettingsMainAddresses PracticeSettingsPhones';
```

--Use FLWOR to manipulate your XML

```
  SELECT FieldDefinition.query(
  N'
    <Fields>
    {
        for $nd in /Fields/*
        return 
        if(local-name($nd)="Field" and contains(sql:variable("@ListOfNames"),$nd/@Name)) then
            <Field PlainTextPersonNotification="True" >{$nd/@*}</Field>
        else
            $nd
    }
    </Fields>
  ')  
  FROM @tbl;
```

The result

```
<Fields>
  <CalledDataFormatter Uid="9D7520C3-B507-463F-9CFD-18BDE5A74677" Prefix="PrimaryCare" />
  <Field PlainTextPersonNotification="True" Name="PatientNames" Layout="Name" />
  <Field Name="PatientPrimaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
  <Field Name="PatientSecondaryAddresses" Layout="Address" />
  <Field Name="PatientDOB" Layout="Date" />
  <Field PlainTextPersonNotification="True" Name="PracticeSettingsName" Layout="Date" />
</Fields>
```

#### Short explanation

You can use FLWOR to re-build your XML. We start with the hardcoded `<Fields>`. The we use an iteration over all elements below `<Fields>`.
If their `local-name()` is `Field` and the declared list of names contains the value of `@Name` we build a new `<Field>` element with the need attribute and add all pre-existant attributes. Otherwise we return the element unchanged.